# If an instance of a nn.module inheriting object is called by 2 different sequential layers, are weights shared between them?

Tags: pytorch

Apologies if the terminology in the title is strange or incorrect, I am trying to refer to the following scenario:

As a minimal example, I define a network as follows:

```
class Convolution_Layers(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in, out, kernel):
    super(Convolution_Layers, self).__init__()
  
    self.conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in, out_channels=out, kernel_size=kernel)

    self.conv2d_layers = nn.Sequential(
      self.conv2d,
      nn.ReLU,
    )

  forward(self,x):
    return self.conv2d_layers(x)
    

class Network_Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Network_Model, self).__init__()
    self.basic_conv = Convolution_layers(1,1,3)

    self.subnetwk_1 = nn.ModuleList().append([self.basic_conv])
    self.subnetwk_2 = nn.ModuleList().append([self.basic_conv])

  def forward(self,x1,x2):
    out1, out2 = x1, x2
    for l in self.subnetwk_1:
      out1 = l(x1)
    for l in self.subnetwk_2:
      out2 = l(x2)
    return out1,out2
```

I would like to know if this would result in the weights in subnetwork 1 and 2 being shared, since they come from the same instance of Convolution layers.

Ideally I would like to have the weights be separate, but be able to create the basic convolution block only once, and then re-use it elsewhere. There may be a better way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, the instance shouldn't be called when appended to the module lists. To answer your question, yes both sub-networks will share the same weights since you appended a unique instance and not two.

```
shared_conv = Convolution_layers(1,1,3)
self.subnetwk_1 = nn.ModuleList([shared_conv])
self.subnetwk_2 = nn.ModuleList([shared_conv])
```

What does *"be able to create the basic convolution block only once"* mean? If you are looking to have the two sub-networks share the same architecture but with separate weights, then you need to initialize **two** layers:

```
self.subnetwk_1 = nn.ModuleList([Convolution_layers(1,1,3)])
self.subnetwk_2 = nn.ModuleList([Convolution_layers(1,1,3)])
```

If you want separate sub-networks but share their arguments, you can use keyword arguments and pass a unique dictionary multiple times to the init function:

```
params = dict(in=1, out=1, kernel=3)
self.subnetwk_1 = nn.ModuleList([Convolution_layers(*params)])
self.subnetwk_2 = nn.ModuleList([Convolution_layers(*params)])
```

Or depending on the complexity of your initialization, make use of a helper function, maybe that's what you meant by "`self.basic_conv()`"  in your code snippet:

```
class Network_Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Network_Model, self).__init__()
    self.subnetwk_1 = nn.ModuleList([self.basic_conv()])
    self.subnetwk_2 = nn.ModuleList([self.basic_conv()])

  def basic_conv(self):
      return Convolution_layers(1, 1, 3)
```

Comment: My "convolution layers" is actually a more complicated sequential sub block, that has several options, so I would like to be able to create one instance of it with those options, and then duplicate the structure in different places, but not the weights. So ideally I would not have to initialize it multiple times for each subnetwork, but once at the top of the network class. I believe this could be accomplished by instead defining a function for the nn.sequential assembly, and not using self, however I also need a custom forward method which complicates things..

Comment: "duplicate the structure in different places, but not the weights", so then you would like to have the weights *shared*, correct?

Comment: No, the weights should not be shared, just the general argumentsof the function. Ie, If I wanted to define that the kernel size is 3 for all convolution layers in my network once, instead of having to initialize it for every list. The weights for each subnetwork should be different, just they all have the same arguments for the convolution.

Comment: Ok I see, I think you meant to implement a method `basic_conv` which initializes the conv network with a fixed set of arguments. I edited my answer, see above.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, I have accepted the answer. Thanks